# Predicting Multiple output based on multiple input like Month and Fixed values column

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

[image]

I have a data like shown in image. it is about 25,000 rows. The data containes details about 12 months for past 4 years. I want to predict Client and Position Opened for particular month and particular jobtitle.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df_final['Clientname_numeric'] = le.fit_transform(df_final['ClientName'])
X = df_final[['MONTH','JobTitleID']]
y = df_final[['PositionsOpened','Clientname_numeric']]
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.05 )
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
predictions = clf.predict(x_test)
predictions = predictions.astype(int)
accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
```

I am using above code and getting error
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the package `scikit learn` and the [random forest classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html). I should point out that I only have very superficial knowledge of machine learning, so this might just be the wrong one for your specific case. The `RandomForestClassifier` however allows to predict multiple outputs at once.

In general, given your data, you would approach it like this (using Scikit Learn):

- Split the tables into input columns and output columns. This could propably be done most easily using the `pandas` package. Then split those into training and test subsets. Scikit offers an [off-the-shelf solution for this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
- Create an instance of a classifier like `RandomForestClassifier` and train it using the input- and output-data from your training set (`classifier.train(inputs_train, outputs_train)`)
- Given the inputs of your test data, predict the outputs (`classifier.predict(inputs_predict)`). Decide whether you are satisfied with the predictive quality of your classifier.

Comment: I am not getting good accuracy it is 0.27.Is there any other model which can apply? For every companies it is different graph I am getting so not able to understand what to apply.I have updated above and code is posted there

Answer (score 0):

For classifying multiple outputs, sklearn has [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.multioutput) library, it expects a base estimator like random forests, gradient boosting etc.

The library allows multiple output regression and classification.

Hope this helps!